# How do I pass this path to a bash function?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I've been having trouble moving to directories with spaces in the name, but it I just figured it was a problem with Cygwin and worked around it.

Then I found that I could create symbolic links to those directories which made me maybe think it wasn't Cygwin. Then I remembered I created an alias for `cd` that would list the directory contents and saw this:

```
cdls { cd $1; ls; }
alias cd='cdls'
```

So the problem is when I try this it fails:

```
$ cd /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/
bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

I can see that the space is causing the path to be split into multiple arguments, but how do I join them together again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to explain the problem for the answer to come to me. My solution is:

```
cdls () { cd "$*"; ls ; }
alias cd='cdls'
```

Simple.

Comment: I wouldn't use $* in that alias; it will cause problems if you have a path with multiple spaces in it.  Also, when using $*, you usually want to use "$@" instead, as it's more robust.

Answer (score 3):

Quote it:

```
cdls { cd "$1"; ls; }
```

Quoting in bash can get hairy, since there's multiple levels of interpretation, but it's usually just a matter of playing with it a bit.

Comment: +1: Quote ALL paths in all shell scripts all the time.  Always.

Comment: Aye.  They might be optional to the parser, but not to me!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cdls() { cd "$1"; ls; }
```